# Cannot find module 'mousetrap' for angular2-hotkeys

Tags: c#, node.js, angular, typescript

While using the angular2-hotkeys package which is downloaded from npm i'm facing the following issue.

**steps:**

> 1. Install angular2-hotkeys using npm install angular2-hotkeys --save
> 2. Stop the npm application
> 3. Run npm start
>
> Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
>   http://localhost:51060/mousetrap  Error: XHR error (404 Not Found)
>   loading http://localhost:51060/mousetrap
>         at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange]

Answer (score 0):

Try typings install dt~mousetrap --global --save

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Tried that but it is not working
but i got the following error
error: 'typings' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.